# String matching in perl, find number of matches

Tags: regex, string, perl, pattern-matching, matching

How do I find the `number of of each 2 consecutive characters AA, AC,AG,AT,CC,CA...` in a sequence like this:

```
$sequence = 'AACGTACTGACGTACTGGTTGGTACGA'
```

Overlapping is not allowed i.e the $sequence contains from left to right AA CG TA CT....and not AA AC CG ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@result = $subject =~ m/[ACTG][ATGC]/g;

print scalar(@result);
```

Edit because you completely changed your question :

```
use strict;

my $subject = "AACGTACTGACGTACTGGTTGGTACGA";
my %results = ();
while ($subject =~ m/[ACTG][ATGC]/g) {
    # matched text = $&
        if(exists $results{$&})
        {
            $results{$&}++ 
        }
        else
        {
            $results{$&} = 1;
        }
}

foreach (sort keys %results) {
    print "$_ : $results{$_}\n";
  }
```

Output :

```
AA : 1
CG : 3
CT : 2
GA : 1
GG : 2
TA : 3
TT : 1
```

Final edit : hopefully... thanks to @canavanin

```
use strict;

my $subject = "AACGTACTGACGTACTGGTTGGTACGA";
my %results = ();
while ($subject =~ m/[ACTG][ATGC]/g) {
    # matched text = $&
    $results{$&}++ 
}

foreach (sort keys %results) {
    print "$_ : $results{$_}\n";
  }
```

Comment: I suppose the `...` in the question imply other sequences.

Comment: @Matteo Well I suppose that the OP should then somehow extend this, or give another description of what he wants to match.

Comment: check edited question i need the number of each match (each 2 chars)

Comment: @FailedDev You don't need the if block. Thanks to autovivification you can replace the whole block with $results{$&} ++;